# Extract Config Context YAML information from NetBox

Tags: python, netbox

We have a NetBox instance which we use to store information about virtual machines. The Config Context tab for a virtual machine object is populated with a YAML file structured as such:

```
stuff:
- hostname: myserver
  os: Linux
  os_version: RHEL 8.1
  network:
  - ip_address: 192.168.2.3
    network: ABC
    gateway: 192.168.2.1
  server_type: XYZ
  other_data: Foobar
```

The same data is also available in JSON format.

I am doing extraction of the standard NetBox fields to a CSV file via the following Python script:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
netbox_token = config.get('NetBox', 'token')
netbox_api_base_url = config.get('NetBox', 'api_base_url')
netbox_devices_endpoint = config.get('NetBox', 'devices_endpoint')
nb = pynetbox.api(netbox_api_base_url, token=netbox_token)
nb.http_session.verify = True

vms = nb.virtualization.virtual_machines.all()
csv_file_vms = 'netbox_vms.csv'

with open(csv_file_vms, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Site', 'VCPUs', 'Memory (MB)', 'Disk (GB)', 'IP Address'])
    for vm in vms:
        csv_writer.writerow([vm.name, vm.status, vm.site, vm.vcpus, vm.memory, vm.disk, vm.primary_ip])
```

How do I modify the `writerow()` function to add the data stored in the Config Context, e.g. the `os_version` field?

Comment: Maybe you should read the tag description of [tag:yaml] before you apply it. This isn't a question about YAML. And you don't apply the [tag:ASCII] although both your input and program seem to be specified in that (and would be just as inappropriatte). Please remove the tag as it makes it more difficult to find those questions that are about YAML

Comment: My mistake. I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preface

You will need to add a dedicated column in the first call to `writerow`, and access the relevant VM attribute in consecutive calls inside the `for` loop. As I assume your question revolves more around **attribute access** rather than how to write CSVs - I'll dive deeper into the former;

#### Config Context

The Config Context can be accessed via the `vm.config_context` attribute. The provided YAML example translates to a dictionary with one key `stuff`, which points to a list of items. Each item in that list is a dictionary having keys such as `hostname`, `os_version`, and `network`. The values of the first keys mentioned are strings, but the value of `network` is yet another list. Following is a practical demonstration for accessing such attributes for the given example, while assuming that all list types have one (and only one) item:

```
>>> vms = nb.virtualization.virtual_machines.all()
>>> for vm in vms:
...     print(f"{vm.name=}")
...     print(f"{vm.vcpus=}")
...     print(f"os_version: {vm.config_context['stuff'][0]['os_version']}")
...     print(f"network/gateway: {vm.config_context['stuff'][0]['network'][0]['gateway']}")
...     print(f"other_data: {vm.config_context['stuff'][0]['other_data']}")
...     print("======================")
...
vm.name='VM1'
vm.vcpus=1.0
os_version: RHEL 9.2
network/gateway: 192.168.2.1
other_data: BarFoo
======================
vm.name='vm2'
vm.vcpus=2.0
os_version: RHEL 8.1
network/gateway: 192.168.2.1
other_data: Foobar
======================
>>>
```

#### Solution

A complete answer to your question would include the adaptations required for writing the CSV, so here goes:

```
>>> vms = nb.virtualization.virtual_machines.all()
>>> csv_file_vms = 'netbox_vms.csv'
>>> with open(csv_file_vms, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
...     csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
...     csv_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Site', 'VCPUs', 'Memory (MB)', 'Disk (GB)', 'IP Address', 'OS Version'])
...     for vm in vms:
...         csv_writer.writerow([vm.name, vm.status, vm.site, vm.vcpus, vm.memory, vm.disk, vm.primary_ip, vm.config_context['stuff'][0]['os_version']])
...
68
37
37
>>>
>>> with open(csv_file_vms) as input_file:
...     print(input_file.read())
...
Name,Status,Site,VCPUs,Memory (MB),Disk (GB),IP Address,OS Version
VM1,Active,,1.0,1023,2049,,RHEL 9.2
vm2,Active,,2.0,1025,2051,,RHEL 8.1

>>>
```

---

#### Additional thoughts

If you can change the YAML structure, removing the first dash `-` (from in front of the `hostname` field in your example) can make attribute access simpler, and also represent the reality more accurately; consider the following YAML as a config context for a router:

```
stuff:
  hostname: MyRouter
  os: Linux
  os_version: RHEL 8.1
  network:
  - ip_address: 192.168.1.1
    name: ABC
  - ip_address: 172.16.1.1
    name: DEF
```

Handling such case in code can look like this:

```
>>> for vm in routers:
...     print(f"{vm.name=}")
...     print(f"{vm.vcpus=}")
...     print(f"{vm.config_context['stuff']['os_version']=}")
...     print("Routing:")
...     for network in vm.config_context['stuff']['network']:
...         print(f"{network['name']}: {network['ip_address']}")
...
vm.name='Router1'
vm.vcpus=None
vm.config_context['stuff']['os_version']='RHEL 8.1'
Routing:
ABC: 192.168.1.1
DEF: 172.16.1.1
>>>
```

You may not have to deal with multiple IP addresses in your situation, but you won't need to handle the possibility of a single VM configured (probably erroneously) with multiple OSes.

---

**Note**: This question involves interoperability between client and server functions. I've tested this on python 3.9.18, netbox 3.6.5, and pynetbox 7.2.0. Other versions may behave differently.